# How to read data from simply formatted text file (c++)?

Tags: c++, computational-geometry, mesh, data-storage

Mesh information like points, faces and cells is to be stored into separate files:

e.g. for points file:

---

# points data: x y z

N_Points 100

x1  y1  z1

x2  y2  z2

...

---

cell file:

---

# cells data: cell type and points index - clockwise (6: tri; 9:quad)

N_Cells 20

9 3 1 2 0

9 2 5 6 1

6 2 3 5

...

---

here # is comment, and N_Points  is the size of vector used to store these information.

I used to store these information directly to ascII files with just numbers, in which each line has same format.

For AscII file with comments, name-value pair and numbers, it is more readable, but I have no idea how to read different type of lines from txt file properly. I appreciate any tips to get this simple job done.

Comment: This seems to be a purely programming question and not related (directly) to computational science.

Comment: it is certainly a borderline question for this community. Do you have a data format you envision already? Example? Do you want to look at some existing formats (say, VTU), which would be more general that you need? I think I would be able to give an answer relevant to the community (and possibly helpful to you) if you are more specific.

Comment: @AntonMenshov The mesh geometry information, as well as boundary faces and internal faces (and the neighbor cells) are used for finite volume method (CFD). Some general mesh file format like VTK, STL is not appropriate for this task. Rather than saving all the information in a single ascii file, storing each type of data (e.g. points) in an individual file is easier and more readable.

Comment: @KOF so, do I understand it right, that data excerpts in the questions are samples of what you want to read correctly? Where do comments can appear in the datafile? A representative sample is needed if the current cases in the question do not cover all.

Comment: I guess there are many scientific, open-source codes out there, that do exactly that. One example would be [OpenFOAM](https://github.com/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-dev). It stores its mesh information in several files, see the [user guide](https://cfd.direct/openfoam/user-guide/v7-mesh-description/#x24-1740005.1.2). However, the way this is actually done -- meaning the C++ code -- is buried deep within its sources.

Comment: Dohn Joe: I have been using OpenFOAM 4+ years for my research topics. Nevertheless, i decided to write my own CFD code to solve some specific problems, since it hard to fully understand, and modify the low-lever source code.

Comment: All you need to do is read each line into memory using whatever C or C++ function you care about, and then parse that string to know what you should be doing. If you do this, you would be able to readily see if a read in line starts with the # symbol, letting you know that it is a comment and can be ignored. You could parse for the substring “N_Points”/“N_Cells” to know this line is going to tell you how much data to allocate prior to loading the points/cells. The last case (list of numbers) could be a default situation that is easy to parse regardless of how many numbers there are on a line.